# Is it safe to snug my garage door up to the frame?

Tags: garage-door

I’ve noticed my garage door is a little ways away from the wall when it’s close, but only at the bottom. Is it okay for me to move the track a bit closer to the wall or will that cause problems?

[image: garage door with lights off]

[image: garage door with lights on]

Comment: Too tight can cause rubbing/fiction.  Do you have weather stripping on the outside?  Weather stripping will block opening and have some give to it.

Comment: it is adjustable, so adjust it

Comment: @crip659 I looked for some "garage weather seals" at a local hardware store and they were $100 each, since I'd likely want 3 to cover the frame top to bottom it's a bit more than I'm wanting to spend. That said, if I can get something similar for < 100 altogether I'll probably add those.

Comment: Following up on my comment. Looking at lowes.com the seals are like 10-20 a strip so either the products where in the wrong place or I read the wrong sticker slot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a very, very close look at the garage door hinges.  Are they the same?  No, they are not.  They have numbers on them - #1, #2, #3, etc.  Each one is proscribing a different offset spacing.  Why is that?

Because the vertical track ***is not vertical***.  It is on a slight slope, exactly corresponding to the offset provided by those different numbered hinges.

Thus, as the door comes down, it is "walking" closer to the wall. Raise it 2 feet, you should see a certain gap.  It should make contact with the wall only in the bottom position. And by "contact with the wall" I mean "come up against seals".   It could be the seals are missing.

So sure, you can adjust the track laterally to the wall, but I'm not a fan of a novice tampering with that, because it's probably correct.  If there's a gap, it's because the seals have deteriorated, were never installed, something moved, or someone installed the wrong hinges, or the mechanism is getting alarmingly slack due to wear.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. There are no seals and I've noticed that none of the other "builder homes" in this HOA have seals either. At our last home I put seals up and it was no issue, at this one I'll have to check with the HOA first but I'm sure it's something we can put up. Even still that gap is about the width of a seal anyway so I may just count the days until this garage door gives out then have it all redone.

Comment: I just watched a few videos online about what you were saying. It seems I'll be safe to snug it a big closer as long as I can manually lift the door without it creating any friction against the door jamb.